# Using an array to create an HTML table

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This is my first S.O. question so please be kind.

I have an array of year/month values that looks something like this

[["2012", "1"], ["2013", "3"], ["2013","4"], ["2013", "3"]]

Essentially I have a rails active record that when i am looping through my array if the year and month already exist I dont want to create a new row I want to put the data in one of my 4 columns in a previous existing row.

So the table might look like this

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Month/Year</th>
      <th>Sales</th>
      <th>Tech Support</th>
      <th>Management</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jan/12</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>%nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Mar/13</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Apr/13</td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
      <td>%nbsp;</td>
      <td>10;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Mar/13</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>%nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have if statements that tell me if it's Sales, Tech Support, or Managment so that it knows which column to put it in, my issue.

Essentially what I want is that last row of Mar/13 to say "hey you already have a Mar/13 row, this value should go into one of it's columns (and the data is such that I will never repeat a column.)

Would I be better served by creating the table with ID's for the TD's in rails that match the year/month/column and then assigning the active record to a javascript array that uses those IDs to put the values in using the innerHTML or is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: `Essentially what I want is that last row of Mar/13 to say "hey you already have a Mar/13 row, this value should go into one of it's columns (and the data is such that I will never repeat a column.)` do you mean should go into one of it's existing rows?

Comment: Yes. So some data may be something like Management, March/13, 5 then another piece may be Sales, March/13, 10. Essentially when I get the same Month and Year combo I want to put that piece of data in the row for that month/year but the category will always be only one of 3 (Sales, Tech Support, or Management) it will never have the same month/year and category but the month and year combo could potentially be the same, but not month/year/category.

Comment: So I may have something like 
{year:2012, month:3, category:sales, total:3}
{year:2013, month:3, category:management, total:3}
{year:2013, month:1, category:tech support, total:5}
{year:2013, month:3, category:tech support, total:3}

So when making the table my March 2013 will only have one row but 2 of the 3 columns filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend grouping the data before trying to output any of it in the view, using the data you gave in the comment, we can do something like:

```
data = [
  { name: 'John', year: 2012, month: 3, category: 'sales', total: 3 },
  { name: 'Jacob', year: 2013, month: 3, category: 'management', total: 3 },
  { name: 'Jingleheimer', year: 2013, month: 1, category: 'tech support', total: 5 },
  { name: 'Schmidt', year: 2013, month: 3, category: 'tech support', total: 3 }
]

grouped = data.group_by { |datum| [datum[:year], datum[:month]] }

# Ruby 2.4+
transformed = grouped.transform_values do |values|
  values.each.with_object({}) do |value, result|
    result.merge!("#{value[:category]} Name" => value[:name],
                  value[:category] => value[:total])
  end
end

puts transformed.inspect
# => {[2012, 3]=>{"sales Name"=>"John", "sales"=>3},
#     [2013, 3]=>{"management Name"=>"Jacob", "management"=>3,
#                 "tech support Name"=>"Schmidt", "tech support"=>3},
#     [2013, 1]=>{"tech support Name"=>"Jingleheimer", "tech support"=>5}}

# Ruby < 2.4
transformed = grouped.map do |year_month, values|
  [year_month, values.each.with_object({}) do |value, result|
    result.merge!("#{value[:category]} Name" => value[:name],
                  value[:category] => value[:total])
  end]
end.to_h


puts transformed.inspect
# => {[2012, 3]=>{"sales Name"=>"John", "sales"=>3},
#     [2013, 3]=>{"management Name"=>"Jacob", "management"=>3,
#                 "tech support Name"=>"Schmidt", "tech support"=>3},
#     [2013, 1]=>{"tech support Name"=>"Jingleheimer", "tech support"=>5}}
```

Then you can just iterate that new hash with the `[year, month]` array as the keys and the values being a hash of `category => total_for_category` and output them however you'd like.

Comment: I'm in training all this week, Ill try this once i get back and give you an upvote if i get it working. Thanks.

Comment: So I almost have this working but I had forgot one more thing, my data also has a name attached to each item which I need in my transform as well (I'm using your 2.4)

So a piece of data may look like 
{name:'Jamie', year: 2013, month: 3, category: 'tech support', total: 3 }

When I try to add it on the values.map I get an error of "wrong array length, expected 2, was 3"

The data looks like something I can work with, I just need name too.

Without the name it looks something like
[[["2012", "3"], {"Tech Support"=>"3""}], ["2012","1"],{"Tech Support"=>"5"}]]

How can I add name?

Comment: @Jamie updated my answer with a more extensible solution

Comment: Bingo. That gives me some stuff I can work with to put into an HTML table.

You get the upvote.